# How to simulate sending periodic task on Elastic Beanstalk server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have set up an Elastic Beanstalk server, worker tier. It has a cron.yaml to run a task every hour, like so:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "broadcast-users"
   url: "/broadcast"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
```

I know that it works via SQS sending a message to the worker queue which then gets picked up by that route - but I don't know what that message looks like. I would like to be able to test the cron job easily, without waiting for the scheduled time to come.

Does anybody what the message would look like from SQS to kick off this cron job? (Or how I can inspect the contents of the messages being sent to SQS?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are sending from the AWS SQS console, try this,

In the `Message Body` tab, put `elasticbeanstalk scheduled job`.

In the `Message Attributes`, put the following:

```
Name: beanstalk.sqsd.path
Type: String
Value: jobs/example-job <- Whatever the URL of  your job is

Name: beanstalk.sqsd.scheduled_time
Type: String
Value: '2018-04-07T20:38:00-04:00' <- When you want it scheduled
```

Note that for the beanstalk.sqsd.path value, I wasn't able to get it to work if I include a leading slash, e.g. `/jobs/example-job` resulted in a lonely message in queue whereas `jobs/example-job` worked.

In my `cron.yaml` I specified the URL to be `/jobs/example-job`, in case you're wondering.

Comment: How did you get the attribute names for `sqsd`? I want to see what are the possible configurations for `beanstalk sqsd`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the contents of the message using the SQS console. The message will probably end up in the dead letter queue.

That being said, the message contents should look like this:

```
{ "taskurl": "broadcast", "taskname": "broadcast-users" }
```

You can also use the SQS console to manually send a message:

- Select the appropriate queue.
- Select "Send a Message" from the "Queue Actions" dropdown.
- Enter a JSON message body (such as `{ "taskurl" : "broadcast", "taskname" : "broadcast-users" }`) and click "Send Message".

In your controller, you can look at the `X-Aws-Sqsd-Taskname` header to determine which task was invoked.

Comment: My worker both processes SQS messages at a /worker route and receives cron tasks at the /broadcast route. When I tried sending that message, it got recieved by the /worker route. Is there an attribute in the JSON that would send it to the /broadcast instead? (Perhaps I'm mistaken in how the cron processing works, maybe it doesn't get triggered from SQS at all?)

Comment: If you send a message manually via the SQS console, it will be sent to whatever endpoint you configured in ElasticBeanstalk. Tasks defined in `cron.yaml` can be sent to arbitrary endpoints via the `url` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon answered this question in their knowledge center ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-cron-job-worker-tier/)). In a nutshell, you can SSH into a worker and use `curl` to immediately test a job via it's URL...

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost/<path>
```

...where `<path>` is the path to the job you want to test. You can also pass parameters using the `-d` option:

```
curl -d param1=value1 -d param2=value2 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost/<path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto the AWS SQS gui (e. g. https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/sqs/v2/home#/queues) and select your queue. If you don't know your queue, navigate to EBS worker configuration and look into the section **Worker**. Watch out for the **Worker queue URL** and select the last part of the url. Should look something like this `awseb-e-3j7sjaqxre-stack-AWSEBWorkerQueue-3WR7QFDPTDEH1`. Search for this in the queue list, select and click the `Send and receive messages` button.

In the **Message Body** textarea put `elasticbeanstalk scheduled job`.

Add three **Message Attributes**

```
Name: beanstalk.sqsd.path
Type: String
Custom Type: (empty)
Value: /jobs/example-job <- cron.url from your cron.yaml

Name: beanstalk.sqsd.task_name
Type: String
Custom Type: (empty)
Value: example-job <- cron.name from your cron.yaml

Name: beanstalk.sqsd.scheduled_time
Type: String
Custom Type: (empty)
Value: '2020-12-06T11:07:00+01:00' <- It did not work without this entry
```

**Send message!**

I don't know why, but the job did not start without the `beanstalk.sqsd.scheduled_time` attribute. Even though the attribute value is ignored! The job started immediately.