# AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

The following post was about starting cron jobs without having to wait for the time:
[How to simulate sending periodic task on Elastic Beanstalk server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211303/how-to-simulate-sending-periodic-task-on-elastic-beanstalk-server)
The first answer seems to be the solution, but where is this documented?
I want to see the documentation as I plan to do the same thing without a schedule

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge is not documented as it's the internal mechanism between sqsd (SQS daemons) in Beanstalks's Worker instances, which might change over time.

Instead of crafting the SQS message like the first answer in your link, you can just directly send a HTTP request to your instance's IP address to trigger the job manually, provided that you configure the security group properly.

Comment: I didn't know that HTTP requests were possible via worker environments. How can I do that?

Comment: since Worker instance is actually just EC2 instance behind the scene, you can go to EC2 console, grab the IP address of the EC2 instance with names matching your Worker environment name. For Port, you can see from the Beanstalk console, in the Environment Variable. After you get IP + port, you can fire a HTTP request directly to your application, without going through SQS